# Which approach is best Bfs or Dfs or Disjoint set for finding all disconnected graphs

Tags: depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, disjoint-sets, disjoint-union

**Which approach should we use to find all disconnected graphs and why ?**

As ***BFS*** and ***DFS*** traversal both are traversal methods and by multiple traversals. We can find all disconnected components.
And another approach can be ***Disjoint Sets*** as used in kruskal (MST) to find disconnected components.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you stated that you need to find **all** disconnected graphs, I would recommend using BFS as it is [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067904/question-about-breadth-first-completeness-vs-depth-first-incompleteness), depth-first search is not. When applied to infinite graphs represented implicitly, BFS will find the goal state, in your scenario, will find all disconnected graphs. DFS, on the other hand, may get lost in parts of the graph that contain no goal state, and essentially, may get lost.